# How to add the appointment data from Angular Scheduler app to a local database?

Tags: django, angular, mongodb, angular-material, syncfusion

I am using the syncfusion ej2 Angular Scheduler App, I want to know that how can i add the appointment data that i provided in it to my local database.
What should be the correct approach to do it in django if i want to add the data to mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

We have validated your reported query “**How to add the appointment data from Angular Scheduler app to a local database?**” at our end. A quick start project that available in the below link helps you to create the Syncfusion Angular Scheduler with Mongo DB. We are not aware of the Django. So, we suggest you refer to the below link for work with Angular Scheduler with Mongo DB.

**Sample:** https://github.com/SyncfusionExamples/ej2-angular-scheduler-mongodb

Kindly try the above sample and get back to us if you need any further assistance.

**UG(Data binding with Angular Scheduler component):** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/schedule/data-binding/